# Spring boot taking long time to start

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a spring boot application where it listens to a RabbitMQ queue. 
The problem is when i run my application it hangs at particular step at
hibernate and it takes around 10 minutes to further continue.

Below is where it hangs

```
INFO [] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO [] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3338 ms
INFO [] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService  'metricsExecutor'
INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
 INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
 INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy}
 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
```

Below is the timing info

```
2015-07-08 09:31:16,714 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
2015-07-08 09:31:16,717 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy}
2015-07-08 09:31:16,717 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-07-08 09:31:16,895 [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
```

**In the above line it hangs for 8 min, and then it generates the below log waiting for any message.**

```
15-07-14 15:36:22,917 [main] INFO [] com.test.myApp.reporting.service.Application
 - Starting Application on hyd-rupakular-m.local with PID 654 (/Users/myUser/code/myRepo/target/classes started by rupakulr in /Users/myuser/myRepo/xyzabc)
2015-07-14 15:36:22,966 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5fa0d903: startup date [Tue Jul 14 15:36:22 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-07-14 15:36:24,023 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-integration-context.xml]
2015-07-14 15:36:24,332 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean - Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/Users/rupakulr/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2015-07-14 15:45:09,646 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-07-14 15:45:09,646 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-07-14 15:45:09,646 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-07-14 15:45:09,647 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-07-14 15:45:09,647 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/trace],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-07-14 15:45:09,647 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/shutdown],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.ShutdownMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2015-07-14 15:45:09,647 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/manage/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-07-14 15:45:09,700 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-07-14 15:45:09,708 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-07-14 15:45:09,708 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#1' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-07-14 15:45:09,709 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-07-14 15:45:09,712 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor:name=org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0,type=WireTap]
2015-07-14 15:45:09,726 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#1': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor:name=org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#1,type=WireTap]
2015-07-14 15:45:09,730 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,type=HeaderValueRouter]
2015-07-14 15:45:09,745 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-07-14 15:45:09,749 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase -2147483648
2015-07-14 15:45:09,750 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 0
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {router} as a subscriber to the 'reporting-dealer-compliance-dealer-list-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.reporting-dealer-compliance-dealer-list-channel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {object-to-json-transformer} as a subscriber to the 'reporting-dealer-compliance-dealer-compliance-json-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.reporting-dealer-compliance-dealer-compliance-json-channel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {logging-channel-adapter:logging-channel.adapter} as a subscriber to the 'logging-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.logging-channel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started logging-channel.adapter
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {stream:outbound-channel-adapter(character):std-out-channel.adapter} as a subscriber to the 'std-out-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.std-out-channel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:09,751 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started std-out-channel.adapter
2015-07-14 15:45:10,968 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway - started org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway#0
2015-07-14 15:45:10,968 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {amqp:outbound-channel-adapter:invalidMessageChannelAdapter} as a subscriber to the 'invalid-message-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:10,968 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.invalid-message-channel' has 2 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:10,968 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started invalidMessageChannelAdapter
2015-07-14 15:45:10,968 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {service-activator} as a subscriber to the 'failed-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:10,968 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.failed-channel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {amqp:outbound-channel-adapter:failedMessageChannelAdapter} as a subscriber to the 'failed-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.failed-channel' has 2 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started failedMessageChannelAdapter
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain - started org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {chain} as a subscriber to the 'reporting-dealer-compliance-inbound-channel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.reporting-dealer-compliance-inbound-channel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain - started org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {chain} as a subscriber to the 'prepare-csv' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application:8204.prepare-csv' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:10,969 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4
2015-07-14 15:45:10,971 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'requestMappingEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=requestMappingEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:10,979 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'environmentEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=environmentEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:10,986 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'healthEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=healthEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:10,992 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'beansEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=beansEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:10,997 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'infoEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=infoEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,003 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'metricsEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=metricsEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,009 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'traceEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=traceEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,014 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'dumpEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=dumpEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,020 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'autoConfigurationAuditEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=autoConfigurationAuditEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,026 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'shutdownEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=shutdownEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,032 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,037 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-07-14 15:45:11,037 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'application:8204.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-07-14 15:45:11,037 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2015-07-14 15:45:11,037 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2015-07-14 15:45:11,089 [main] INFO [] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8204"]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,095 [main] INFO [] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8204"]
2015-07-14 15:45:11,100 [main] INFO [] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2015-07-14 15:45:11,112 [main] INFO [] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8204 (http)
2015-07-14 15:45:11,115 [main] INFO [] com.test.myApp.reporting.service.Application - Started Application in 528.444 seconds (JVM running for 529.101)
```

we are experiencing a lot of problem when developing our app, every time we make some changes we have to wait 8 min to test our changes.

Comment: Unfortunately your log is missing timing informations. At which step exactly does your app hang?

Comment: the application hangs at last step in the above  [main] INFO [] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}, here it waits for around 8 min and then continues.

Comment: You probably want to include the entry immediately following the entry that hangs, just in case it says something like "INFO Cache warmed" or whatever.

Comment: Sry, i could not get you, could you please elaborate

Comment: The point at which things stop is where Hibernate starts to scan for entity classes.  The steps that happen at this point are: 1. Scan relevant packages for entity classes; 2. Generate meta-data for the scanned classes; 3. Generate/update database schema, if required (by the configuration); 4. Run data import script (if configured as `import.sql` in the classpath).  Do you expect any of all of these steps to happen at this stage?  If yes, examine the quantum of each step (how many packages, how many classes, how many tables, how big an import script, etc.).

Comment: If it helps, my app stops at that same point for about 5 minutes on an Amazon t1.micro instance while it takes less than 2 minutes for the same activity on an m1.medium instance.  Your hardware could also be a bottleneck.

Comment: #1 Here are some ways to debug the application: changing root log level to DEBUG / CPU profiling / generating a thread dump can help figuring out where exactly the application is spending that 8 minutes. Even simple tools like visualvm (under JDK_HOME/bin) can help in the later two. #2 Is there a chance the application is not able to connect to the DB and the connection times out after 8 mins?

Comment: the connection does not timeout after 8 min, after 8 minutes it reads the message from rabbitMQ that i published.

Comment: I used the visualVM and observed the ThreadDump, it gets stuck with below message  ""VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007f7fb6002800 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition 
", any pointers ?

Comment: take a thread dump while it's hanging (`kill -3 $PID` on *nixes, `ctl-break` in the console on windows) and post a link to the thread dump. What you are looking for is the thread that is in a RUNNING state. Have a look at the method that is blocking, this should tell you more or less exactly what it is waiting for.

Comment: Have you figured anything out on this?

Comment: Hibernate initialization could take a lot of time if your application contains a lot of model objects and connection to the database is not good. Are you connecting to the local DB?

Answer (score 8):

In case you are running your application on Linux, try to add this property to the java commandline:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

E.g.:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx75m -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar
```

I had a similar problem, although it did not take 8 minutes but only around 3 to start the application, and this solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed this issue for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think I faced with the similar issue. In my case time to start was proportional to the database size. And the entire problem was that hibernate (we use hibernate-core-5.0.2-Final) loads full metadata from DB just for obtaining Dialect value.

We now use following property to disable:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

But make sure you specify 'spring.jpa.database-platform' value correct.

Here is related part of `JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java` file:

```
@Override
public JdbcEnvironment initiateService(Map configurationValues, ServiceRegistryImplementor registry) {
    final DialectFactory dialectFactory = registry.getService( DialectFactory.class );

    // 'hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults' is a temporary magic value.
    // The need for it is intended to be alleviated with future development, thus it is
    // not defined as an Environment constant...
    //
    // it is used to control whether we should consult the JDBC metadata to determine
    // certain Settings default values; it is useful to *not* do this when the database
    // may not be available (mainly in tools usage).
    boolean useJdbcMetadata = ConfigurationHelper.getBoolean(
            "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults",
            configurationValues,
            true
    );

    if ( useJdbcMetadata ) {
        final JdbcConnectionAccess jdbcConnectionAccess = buildJdbcConnectionAccess( configurationValues, registry );
        try {
            final Connection connection = jdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection();
            try {
                final DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
                if ( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {
                    log.debugf(
                            "Database ->\n"
                                    + "       name : %s\n"
                                    + "    version : %s\n"
                                    + "      major : %s\n"
                                    + "      minor : %s",
                            dbmd.getDatabaseProductName(),
                            dbmd.getDatabaseProductVersion(),
                            dbmd.getDatabaseMajorVersion(),
                            dbmd.getDatabaseMinorVersion()
                    );
                    log.debugf(
                            "Driver ->\n"
                                    + "       name : %s\n"
                                    + "    version : %s\n"
                                    + "      major : %s\n"
                                    + "      minor : %s",
                            dbmd.getDriverName(),
                            dbmd.getDriverVersion(),
                            dbmd.getDriverMajorVersion(),
                            dbmd.getDriverMinorVersion()
                    );
                    log.debugf( "JDBC version : %s.%s", dbmd.getJDBCMajorVersion(), dbmd.getJDBCMinorVersion() );
                }

                Dialect dialect = dialectFactory.buildDialect(
                        configurationValues,
                        new DialectResolutionInfoSource() {
                            @Override
                            public DialectResolutionInfo getDialectResolutionInfo() {
                                try {
                                    return new DatabaseMetaDataDialectResolutionInfoAdapter( connection.getMetaData() );
                                }
                                catch ( SQLException sqlException ) {
                                    throw new HibernateException(
                                            "Unable to access java.sql.DatabaseMetaData to determine appropriate Dialect to use",
                                            sqlException
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
                return new JdbcEnvironmentImpl(
                        registry,
                        dialect,
                        dbmd
                );
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                log.unableToObtainConnectionMetadata( e.getMessage() );
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    jdbcConnectionAccess.releaseConnection( connection );
                }
                catch (SQLException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.unableToObtainConnectionToQueryMetadata( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    // if we get here, either we were asked to not use JDBC metadata or accessing the JDBC metadata failed.
    return new JdbcEnvironmentImpl( registry, dialectFactory.buildDialect( configurationValues, null ) );
}
```